# Responsive Design with Amazon Checkout

Tags: responsive-design, e-commerce, amazon-product-api

A client is looking into using Amazon Checkout (http://www.amazonservices.com/content/amazon-checkout-payments.htm/ref=as_left_cba#!customer-experience) for the e-commerce portion of their site. They would also like to creative the site responsively. Since Amazon Checkout is not responsive, I presume this can not be done. Does anyone have any experience with this or have a bit more knowledge about the flexibility of Amazon Checkout making this possible?

Answer (score 0):

IMO as web developers it is our job to do our very best to thoroughly research a requested API or service, and most times the API or service's competitors as well.  As webworkers we can sometimes play a huge role in helping our clients to make the best choices for their technology service providers.  This includes full disclosure when offering services that benefit the developer/firm, as well as plainly laying out the pros and cons in non-geek, plain English.

***That being said***, if your client just won't budge and is clinging to a non-responsive or stodgy, requirement-laden integration (read: non-responsive `<iframe>`) consider using design and user experience to draw a clear line between your pretty responsive site, and their ugly old code from 1998.

Consider using things like [modals](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) to differentiate the checkout experience, or simply use a `target="_blank"` to fire off a new tab or window, just make sure the user can easily find their way back to your site after the checkout is complete.

Another alternative might be to look into creating [1-click buttons](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/helpTab/Checkout-by-Amazon/Integrating-with-Checkout-by-Amazon/Creating-a-Checkout-Button-HTML-Integration#CreatingACheckoutButton) if you are interested in having a modified shopping experience on a mobile-size screen.